# Listview overlaps with ToolBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-toolbar

I am using android design support library.

`ListView` first row overlaps with `Toolbar` widget.

In my `MainActivity` i added coordination layout and in first TAB fragment added `ListView` layout.

But first row of the `ListView` cut because if `Toolbar` tabs.

How to fix this problem?

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordi"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFEB3B"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/plus" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/layout_drawer_header" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


list_view.xml:
-------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
```

Comment: Try adding this behaviour `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar problem and after following the top answer, I rewrote my code to use `RecyclerView` and got the same issue. I then added this behavior to my content layout and it worked

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Comment: Sorry Zack but in which part of the question xml sample should I add this?

Answer (score 4):

`CoordinatorLayout`'s `ScrollingViewBehavior` only works with views that support nested scrolling (for example `RecyclerView`). `ListView` does not support it by default, so the `CoordinatorLayout` is not handling the position of the `ListView` correctly.

If you want all the scrolling behaviours of the design support library, you could try converting your list to a `RecyclerView`. `ListView` also gained nested scrolling support in API 21, which you could try to enable with `setNestedScrollingEnabled(true)`, but that will obviously only work on Lollipop and newer versions.

More information here: [ScrollingViewBehavior for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612453/scrollingviewbehavior-for-listview)

Comment: It is not correct. `ListView` support the nested Scroll behavior with API 21+ Chech here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696611/design-lib-coordinatorlayout-collapsingtoolbarlayout-with-gridview-listview/30885092#30885092.
Also you should not use a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same problem where part of my listview is overlapped by toolbar.
I'm able to make it work in android 4.4.4(Kitkat) but the issue could not be resolved in android 5.1(Lolipop)
So, Here is my solution to resolve this issue

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

The mistake which I made was that, adding the *listview* in *activity_main.xml* which we should not add instated we should add *listview* in *app_bar_main.xml*

**layout/app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/AartilistView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Other files containing the code is
**layout/nav_header_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material_red"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout/item_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Description"
        android:id="@+id/icon_text"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon_image"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu/activity_main_drawer.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_info_details" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
                android:title="About us" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_rate" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_star"
                android:title="Rate App" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share App" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_facebook" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_fb"
                android:title="Follow me on Facebook" />
        </group>

        <item android:title="Communicate">
            <menu>
                 <item android:id="@+id/nav_whatsapp" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_whatsapp"
                    android:title="Whatsapp us to share your" />
                 <item android:id="@+id/nav_email" android:icon="@drawable/sym_action_email"
                    android:title="Tell us how you feel about App" />
             </menu>
        </item>
</menu>
```

make sure you build the project and then run it.
Don't add your listview in activity_main.xml instead add it in app_bar_main.xml which you'll include in activity_main.xml anyways.

Answer (score 1):

XML design showing unchecked "Show layout decorations":
[image: .xml Design showing unchecked "Show Layout Decorations"]

XML design showing checked "Show layout decorations":
[image: .xml Design showing checked "Show Layout Decorations"]

After checking this option, add your ListView and set default margins (Eg. 8dp). This will NOT hide the first item in list view.

Answer (score 0):

Use layout margin bottom/top property, and adjust your listview not to cover up the space where the toolbar resides.

Answer (score -1):

You could add some padding to the `Toolbar` using

```
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
```

That should add some space between the two elements